# Apache rewrite rule: is it possible to redirect a request to null

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a small issue to quickly fix with a Js that request a page that should be empty.

Is it possible to redirect that request to something like /dev/null ?

Thanks in advance!

Pv

Comment: So you want this to be a successful operation, i.e. it returns an HTTP 200 response, but the body of the response must be empty?

Answer (score 3):

Since the response will still contain headers, a really empty response is unrealistic.

An empty page is, of course, entirely doable; just point it to a resource that is empty:

```
touch empty.txt
```